# Generic type constraint on generic type

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I have a class like this:

```
public class Proxy<TClient>()
    where TClient : ClientBase<TChannel>
{

}
```

I want to be able to specify something like this:

```
where TClient : ClientBase<TChannel>
where TChannel : class
```

but *without* specifying it in the class definition like so:

```
public class Proxy<TClient, TChannel>()
```

Is there a way to do this or am I required to have the second type definition as above?

Comment: Where did `TChannel` come from?

Comment: No, you cannot do that, and yes, you need to specify the second generic parameter in your Proxy declaration: `Proxy<TClient, TChannel>`.

Comment: @Dan `TChannel` is required for `ClientBase` (which comes from System.ServiceModel). There is no non-generic alternative.

Comment: I understand that, but in your code, it's not defined anywhere.  You have to declare it as a generic type parameter, which is what you're trying to avoid.  What you ask for cannot be done.

Comment: What do you do with `TClient` in your class?  You could potentially omit `TClient` and just declare members using `ClientBase<TChannel>`, depending on usage.

Comment: @Dan I'm not well versed enough in the functionality of the C# compiler to be able to say, but it seems like it *should* be possible. The issue is that I don't care what `TChannel` is, but I have to specify it just to make the code compile. If someone actually is well versed in how the C# compiler works I'd love some insight on this. And even if you do need to specify a constraint for `TChannel`, I would think that this would theoretically be possible.

Comment: @DanPuzey - I need `TClient`, unfortunately. But I like your logic :). +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. You have to include `TChannel` as a generic type parameter of `Proxy`.

One of the options to get over this “limitation” (in quotes because it is a by-design feature that arises from how the C# type system works) is to use an interface which each channel would be supposed to implement:

```
public interface IChannel { … }

public class Proxy<TClient>()
    where TClient : ClientBase<IChannel>
{ 
}

public class MyObscureChannel : IChannel { … }

public class MyObscureClient : ChannelBase<MyObscureChannel> { … }

…

var client = new Proxy<MyObscureClient>(…); // MyObscureChannel is implied here
```